# How to make disk accept 2TB Seagate?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have a 2TB external hard drive from Seagate that will not show up on Windows 10, but it will on Mac OS. I have followed the steps on [Seagate's website](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/usb-external-troubleshooter-003581en/), in particular populating the disk and noted the disk number (3). Then under Disk management I have found the following

[image: the following].

Are the 2TB too big for the disk and is there a way to resolve this?

EDIT: The drive is formatted APFS, which is not supported by Windows 10.

Comment: How is it formatted? Windows cannot read HFS+ or APFS without 3rd party software support. Check on the Mac - Get Info on the mounted volume.

Comment: If it shows up in Disk Management but not in File Explorer, it's likely formatted for Mac.

Comment: Assign letters to the disks. It seems that you have not done it yet.

Comment: Don't do anything to it if it's HFS+ or APFS - Windows is likely to break something. Check it on the Mac first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Indeed, the formatting is APFS. I will edit this in the post and accept any answer that gives or links to a possible solution.

Comment: Of the suggestions on the link, I'd go for Paragon, but that's merely one opinion.

Comment: Or reformat it to exFAT?

Comment: You could. It would be cross-platform to an extent, as both can read/write it natively. ExFAT doesn't support file permissions properly though.